# Fish Shell: Delete All Except

Tags: fish

Using Fish, how can I delete the contents of a directory except for certain files (or directories). Something like `rm !(file1|file2)` from bash, but fishier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such feature in fish - that's issue [#1444](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1444).

You can do something like

```
rm (string match -rv '^file1$|^file2$' -- *)
```

Note that this will fail on filenames with newlines in them.

Or you can do the uglier:

```
set -l files *
for file in file1 file2
    if set -l index (contains -i -- $file $files)
        set -e files[$index]
    end
end
rm $files
```

which should work no matter what the filenames contain.

Or, as mentioned in that issue, you can use find, e.g.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -a ! \( -name 'file1' -o -name 'file2' \)
```